# Генерация hex-кодов градиента на python

Tags: python, hex, linear-gradient

Мне нужно сгенерировать определенное количество hex-кодов линейного градиента между указанными точками начала и окончания (тоже hex).

Я нашел данный пример: https://github.com/benjaminmgross/small-color-gradient-generator/blob/master/color_gen.py
Но хотелось бы поинтересоваться, возможна ли реализация без использования библиотек.

Comment: Ну там все есть что нужно по ссылке. Используйте словари и списки вместо Pandas. А описание linspace почитайте и свою функцию сделайте, она простая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def hex_to_rgb(hex_color: str) -> list:
    """Generate rgb color from hex.

    Args:
        hex_color: str - color for parsing.

    Returns:
        list: r, g, and b shades.
    """
    hex_color = hex_color.lstrip('#')
    bits = 16
    return [int(hex_color[bit:bit+2], bits) for bit in (0, 2, 4)]


def linear_gradient(start_hex: str, finish_hex: str, steps: int = 10) -> dict:
    """Generate linear gradient.

    Args:
        start_hex: str - gradient start color.
        finish_hex: str - gradient end color.
        steps: int, optional - number of colors in the gradient. Defaults to 10.

    Returns:
        dict: three lists under the keys r, g and b, storing the number of values ​​​\
            ​specified in steps for each color.
    """
    start = hex_to_rgb(start_hex)
    finish = hex_to_rgb(finish_hex)
    factor = steps-1
    if factor <= 0:
        return {'r': [finish[0]], 'g': [finish[1]], 'b': [finish[2]]}
    lin_grad = []
    for shade in range(3):
        component_values = []
        for step in range(steps):
            coefficient = (finish[shade] - start[shade]) * step / factor
            component_values.append(int(start[shade] + coefficient))
        lin_grad.append(component_values)
    return {'r': lin_grad[0], 'g': lin_grad[1], 'b': lin_grad[2]}



start_color = '#2E8B57'
finish_color = '#C71585'
gradient_result = linear_gradient(start_color, finish_color, 100)
```

Результат: [image: словарь rgb-кодов][image: градиент от #2E8B57 до #C71585]

Код можно сократить, но я делал под flake8.